# React Hooks must be called in the exact same order in every component render

Tags: reactjs

i found this quite interesting pattern where you enable function based on ternary approach applied on the use state itself but i got this problem where  it says

> React Hook "useState" is called conditionally. React Hooks must be
> called in the exact same order in every component render

```
import React, { useState } from "react";

const App = () => {
  const [enableFirstName, setEnableFirstName] = useState(false);
  const [name, setName] = enableFirstName ? useState("") : ["", () => {}]; #Error is here
  const [lastName, setLastName] = useState("");

  const handleChangeName = (e) => {
    setName(e.target.value);
  };

  const handleChangeLastName = (e) => {
    setLastName(e.target.value);
  };
  
  const handleEnableChange = (evt) => {
    setEnableFirstName(!enableFirstName);
  };

  return (
    <div>
    <h1>My name is: {enableFirstName ? name : ''} {lastName}</h1>
    <input type="checkbox" value={enableFirstName} onChange={handleEnableChange} />
    <input type="text" value={name} onChange={handleChangeName} />
    <input type="text" value={lastName} onChange={handleChangeLastName} />
</div>
  );
};

export default App;
```

Comment: What are you trying to achieve with `enableFirstName ? useState("") :` ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

React doesn't allow you to call hooks conditionally.
Remove the condition in the second `useState`:

```
const [enableFirstName, setEnableFirstName] = useState(false);
const [name, setName] = useState("");
const [lastName, setLastName] = useState("");
```

Even if you don't need the `name` because `enableFirstName` is false - simply ignore it, leave empty string and handle conditional logic in the component methods if necessary.